# TIme (Date object) not updating in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have to restart server to get the time updated in IST object.
 
Development Environment -- "Cloud9".

Following code extract;

```
var http = require("http");
var fs = require("fs");
var path = require("path");

var files = {};
var port = process.env.PORT;
var host = process.env.IP;

//Convert time to Indian Standard Time
var IST = new Date(); // Clone UTC Timestamp (once stamped, time not updating here)
IST.setHours(IST.getHours() + 5); // set Hours to 5 hours later
IST.setMinutes(IST.getMinutes() + 30); // set Minutes to be 30 minutes later

var assets = function(req, res){
var serve = function(){
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type' : 'text/html'});
res.write("day:" + IST.getDay());
res.write("day:"+ IST.getDay() + " " + IST.getHours() + " " + IST.getMinutes() + "<br>");
res.write("server time: "+ (new Date()).getDay() + " " + (new Date()).getHours() + " " + (new Date()).getMinutes());
res.end();

};
serve();

};

var app = http.createServer(assets).listen(port,host);
console.log("Listening on " + host + ":" + port);
```

Output (before restarting server):

```
day: 3
day: 3 15 8
server time:  5 3 41
/cse/g1
day: 3
day: 3 15 8
server time:  5 3 48
/cse/g1
day: 3
day: 3 15 8
server time:  5 3 54
/cse/
day: 3
day: 3 15 8
server time:  5 3 55
/cse/g3
day: 3
day: 3 15 8
server time:  5 3 55
```

when this extract is run seperatly it runs and does not shows error.

The output present above is from the log of the server that i started 2 days earlier.

Today i restarted server and now the Output is:

Ouput (after restarting server):

```
day: 5
day: 5 10 54
server time:  5 5 25
/cse/
day: 5
day: 5 10 54
server time:  5 5 25
/cse/
day: 5
day: 5 10 54
server time:  5 5 26
/cse/
day: 5 
day: 5 10 54
server time:  5 5 26
/cse/
day: 5
day: 5 10 54
server time:  5 5 26
/cse/
day: 5
day: 5 10 54
server time:  5 5 26
/cse/
day: 5
day: 5 10 54
server time:  5 5 27
/cse/
day: 5
day: 5 10 54
server time:  5 5 29
```

Preview can be checked at https://nodejs-basic-prashantdawar.c9.io/.

Please refresh after few minutes and note the output every time. you see the ouput as shown above.
How to correctly show updated time??

Gist of modified code for simplicity: https://gist.github.com/a36a893a772f3582d0d4.git

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
var http = require("http"),
    fs   = require("fs"),
    path = require("path");

var files = {};
var port  = process.env.PORT,
    host  = process.env.IP;

var assets = function (req, res) {

    //Convert time to Indian Standard Time
    var IST = new Date(); // Clone UTC Timestamp (once stamped, time not updating here)
    IST.setHours(IST.getHours() + 5); // set Hours to 5 hours later
    IST.setMinutes(IST.getMinutes() + 30); // set Minutes to be 30 minutes later


    var serve = function () {
        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'text/html'
        });
        res.write("day:" + IST.getDay() + "<br>");
        res.write("day:" + IST.getDay() + " " + IST.getHours() + " " + IST.getMinutes() + "<br>");
        var serverTime = new Date();
        res.write("server time: " + serverTime.getDay() + " " + serverTime.getHours() + " " + serverTime.getMinutes());
        res.end();
    };

    serve();
};

var app = http.createServer(assets).listen(port, host);
console.log("Listening on " + host + ":" + port);
```

Notice how the IST variable is declared in the callback function. So every time you have a request, IST variable date will be updated.

Comment: Thanks. want to upvote , but reputation too low. Sorry for that.